# C# Host Socket Server using GoDaddy Shared Hosting

Tags: c#, sockets, server, shared-hosting

Please excuse my lack of experience, I'm not sure where to begin, I'm googling my self in circles.

Would it be possible to create a socket server (c#) console application and host it on a goDaddy shared hosting account. I'm trying to create a server/client application but I'm stuck with a shared hosting account from goDaddy.

Also, is there a significant difference between sockets and webSockets?

If you could point me in the right direction, or at the very least let me know if its even possible...?

**EDIT:**
I have a WPF application running of a windows surface tablets (3 tablets), the application is for time tracking, it gives people the ability to login / logout using an RFID reader. For the backend I'm using Web API and the issue is latency. It sometimes takes up to 15 seconds for the application to create a connection, authenticate (if not authenticated) and get the person's status.

Needless to say staff are impatient and I see their point (they should be able to swipe, confirm and walk away), I'd like to be under 2 seconds max. So I figured if I can keep a connection open through-out operating hours (sockets), then fetching a user's status should be near instantaneous.

I'm open to any suggestion/recommendation. I can't thank you enough! Thnx a million!

Comment: By "shared hosting" do you mean website hosting? If so, then no: those servers are heavily firewalled and only allow port 80 and 443 in, and your application must be provided as an ASP.NET application as well.

Comment: You won't be able to host a console application or even a websocket server on a shared hosting plan like that. Maybe if we knew what you were trying to do, we could point you in the right direction.

Comment: If you're just tinkering, you could probably do well with the free tier of Azure or something similar.

Comment: Would it be possible using Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without getting into some rather hinkey maneuvers that would probably get your account shut down you would be very hard pressed to run a socket server on godaddy shared hosting. Mechanically you'd need to be able to execute a custom .exe which would need to be executed -- and kept executing -- by something somewhere. This executable would also need to listen on a particular TCP port which would most likely be either in use like ports 80 and 443 or would likely be firewalled from the rest of the world.

Hosting a web socket app would be tricky -- first they would need to have ugraded to IIS 8 and cursory tests indicate they are still on IIS 7.5. Second, they would need to permit websocket usage which is not something likely to be enabled on shared hosts. I think resource usage would be a challenge if you managed to run these two traps.

It would help quite a bit to understand what you are doing but if it is something that requires either sockets or even web sockets you are looking at a class of hosting above the godaddy shared options.